# Why does Prefab NDK Dependencies not work?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have some native code that depends on OpenSSL. In the beginning, I tried manually compiling OpenSSL for Android, but it simply wouldn't find the definitions.
Then I decided to move on and try using Prefabs instead. I followed the example [Android NDK Prefab example](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/main/prefab/prefab-dependency), but it just doesn't work.

My CMakeLists contains the following

```
find_package(openssl REQUIRED CONFIG)

target_link_libraries(
    testproject
    openssl::openssl)
```

My build.gradle:

```
android {
compileSdk 31

defaultConfig {
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags ""
        }
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

buildFeatures {
    prefab true
}
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        version "3.10.2"
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.ndk.thirdparty:openssl:1.1.1l-beta-1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

But whenever I compile, I get

```
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "openssl" with any
  of the following names:

opensslConfig.cmake
openssl-config.cmake
```

Looking into the downloaded data, I see the openSSL folder under cmake only contains `opensslConfigVersion.cmake` and not `opensslConfig.cmake`, as it does with curl, for example.

What is going on? Why is this not working? Any help is appreiciated.

Comment: The sample ([with the packages updated](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/pull/826)) builds fine for me. If I add a `find_package(openssl CONFIG REQUIRED)` I get an error for the duplicate definition of the openssl package (curl already imported it) showing that `opensslConfig.cmake` definitely exists. I assume you've tried a clean build? Does the sample build for you?

Answer (score 0):

The `curl-ssl` example in the [ndk samples](gitclo https://github.com/android/ndk-samples)
only builds because it allows C++ and STL.
But `openssl` is C only.

The [maven repo ndk thirdparty](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.ndk.thirdparty)
links to the sources for the prefab package for `openssl` and `curl` among others,
i.e. [ndkports](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/ndkports).

There is no reference to C++ there for `openssl`.
It seems the problem is by [prefab](https://github.com/google/prefab).

I found this issues: [OpenSSL forces c++_shared – why?](https://github.com/google/prefab/issues/134)

Judging from this and other issues there is a high chance that `prefab` might just not fit your and my project as of yet.

You don't get an according `curl` message, because `curl` depends on `openssl`,
which makes the latter build first.
If you remove `openssl` you get:

```
  Error: curl depends on unknown dependency openssl
```

I first did have no `ndkVersion` defined, as you.
Only afterward I got more error messages:

```
... //openssl/crypto. Rejected the following libraries:
C/C++: prefabandroid.arm64-v8a: User is targeting armeabi-v7a but library is for arm64-v8a
```

Removing `armeabi-v7a` from

```
        ndk.abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
```

I got

```
... //openssl/ssl. Rejected the following libraries:
C/C++: prefabandroid.arm64-v8a: User requested no STL but library requires libc++
C/C++: prefabandroid.armeabi-v7a: User is targeting arm64-v8a but library is for armeabi-v7a
```

Another sign that prefab is ealily getting confused.

And because it was not built finally:

```
    Could not find a package configuration file provided by "openssl" with any
    of the following names:
··
      opensslConfig.cmake
      openssl-config.cmake
```

The file refers to

```
app/.cxx/cmake/debug/prefab/arm64-v8a/prefab/lib/aarch64-linux-android/cmake/openssl/opensslConfig.cmake
```

This has links that point to `~/.gradle`.
So the include and link directories are somewhere deep down in `~/.gradle` and not under the project directory.

One can include native code directly [via cmake](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code).
The [ndkports](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/ndkports) are a starting point for to configuration.